# Android flow for Simple API call

Tags: android, rest, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I make simple api calls that return success or error. I use Livedata or SingleLiveEvent for making an api call and updating the UI based on the result. Can I replace them with flow?
As I understand, flow is more meant for processing stream of data and update the Ui when there is change in the data. For example change of data in database.

Please help me understand this better

Answer (score 2):

LiveData is part of Android jetpack, just like any observable data holder class but with lifecycle-awareness built specifically for android whereas flow is part of kotlin and are built on top of coroutines and aren't built specifically for Android.
If you want to use flow, you can replace livedata with stateflow (mutableLivedata with mutableStateFlow). For better migration
[Use this link](https://link.medium.com/Az3MTk5rQAb)